# getResponseCode weather times out nor reads response

Tags: android, sockets, timeout, httpurlconnection

I have an android application which can upload some json data to a PHP script which stores the data in a database.

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
        connection.setReadTimeout(3000000);
        long tim = System.currentTimeMillis();
        connection.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
        connection.getOutputStream().flush();
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            long dur = System.currentTimeMillis() - tim;
            String response = IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            throw new IOException(connection.getResponseCode() + " " + response);
        }
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
```

The data arrives at the script and the scripts stores the data into the database.

When the client uploads a huge amount of data the request takes about 15 minutes, though it completes. The data is completly written into the database and the php script sends it's response.

But when it takes that long the getResponseCode() function never returns. When i hit pause in the debugger it shows me the following stack:

[image: Stack]

Any idea what's running wrong?

I'm running an emulator on API level 23.

It seems that the connection gets lost but android does not detect it.